# Java on Mac OS X Server: game over?

Tags: java, macos, deprecated, headless, osx-server

As a developer currently working on a Web app that uses a Java/Tomcat backend, [the recent announcement by Apple to deprecate Java](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html) is causing me some consternation. Mainly because I'm planning on hosting this Web app on Mac OS X Server (already on 10.5, soon to be on 10.6).

From http://www.appleoutsider.com/2010/10/22/java/:

> Since the Intel transition, building a server VM for Darwin is almost trivial.

Is this actually true? Is there a document somewhere that describes how to build a headless Java VM for Mac OS X Server?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007252/need-guidance-on-alternative-jvms-for-apple-os-x

Comment: Asking to reopen because (1) A question about building a VM for Java is off-topic? Since when? (2) The other questions mentioned aren't discussing Mac OS X *Server*, which I am (3) I want a *headless* JVM, unlike those other questions

Comment: I don't think that this qualifies as "not related to programming or software development." Voting to reopen

Comment: Why is this off-topic? Building a JVM is certainly related to software development.

Comment: @Grodriguez please vote to reopen!

Comment: @Shaggy: Not enough rep, sorry.

Comment: Server VM yes, Aqua-friendly frontend no.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to build [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) on Mac OS X without much trouble. It only has Windows and X11 frontends but since you are asking for a headless JVM, this should not be a problem for you.

Pre-built binaries of OpenJDK are also available for Mac OS X. See the SoyLatte project (a Java Research License may be required):

- http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/#get

Note that SoyLatte has recently become part of the OpenJDK BSD-Port project:

- http://openjdk.java.net/projects/bsd-port/

Comment: I keep seeing people suggest SoyLatte, but isn't the binary distribution under the Java Research Licences, which seems fairly restrictive.

Comment: Yes, SoyLatte requires a Java Research License (I mentioned this in my answer). Note however that SoyLatte has become part of OpenJDK,and OpenJDK binaries do not require a Java Research License. Pre-built OpenJDK6 binaries are available for MacOS X (not yet the case for OpenJDK7).

Answer (score 2):

Build instructions for OpenJDK on OS X Snow Leopard can be found at http://wikis.sun.com/display/OpenJDK/BSDPort. Apparently. Tomcat runs fine with OpenJDK, so you shouldn't have any real problems (even if Oracle never step up and provide an "official" JDK).