# Apple deprecates Java, what are our technical options as programmers?

Tags: java, oracle, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need guidance on alternative JVMs for Apple OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007252/need-guidance-on-alternative-jvms-for-apple-os-x)

So that's it, Apple may not be producing a JVM themselves nor shipping it with OS X anymore:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/10/apple-deprecates-java

We've got a huge Java application running on Windows, Linux and OS X (and OS X is a big part of our [rich] userbase), what will, as developers, our options be?

Will it be realistic to run our app on another OS X JVM (an Oracle one)?

Or is a move away from Java to be considered?  If so, what would that technically mean? Try to use some automated porting tool (not unlike Excelsior Jet for Windows, is there anything similar for OS X?)? Rewrite our entire app (which would be huge) to Objective-C and maintain two different versions? (a Java one and an Objective-C one?).

We may decide to drop OS X support altogether too, at least as long as Microsoft or Oracle do not kill Java on Windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007252/need-guidance-on-alternative-jvms-for-apple-os-x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017223/java-on-mac-os-x-server-game-over

Comment: The options will be the same as they are on *any* platform without a system JVM: ship one or ask your customers to go and get one. And yes, that means a potential hassle with JVM-vendor-n-version compatibility.

Comment: One of the longstanding hassles of Java is on many platforms it requires a large dependency.  Major platforms (such as Windoze) don't include a JVM out of the box.  Your app has to embed the JVM or make users install it.  Neither option is nice :(

Answer (score 4):

> Will it be realistic to run our app on another OS X JVM (an Oracle one)?

That depends on how GUI intensive your application is, and how much you / your users care about having a fast GUI and the Mac "user experience" for the Mac version of your app.

But yes, it could be totally realistic.  Wait and see what Oracle does, and in the meantime, try out [Soy Latte](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/#get).

> Or is a move away from Java to be considered?

Depends how much effort you have to burn.  And how much effort you can justify for supporting Mac users.  No matter how you do it, you'll end up having to support two codebases.

> We may decide to drop OS X support altogether too ...

That's realistic.

> ... at least as long as Microsoft or Oracle do not kill Java on Windows.

That's ridiculous FUD-mongering!

Microsoft can't do it, because they have no control of the Java codebase.  (If they tried to do it by backdoor means, they'd be up against the wall for anti-trust violations ... all over the world.)

Oracle would be insane to try to do it for many reasons.  Besides, they can't (in theory) because the OpenJDK for Windows codebase is open source and there other existing high quality Java implementations for Windows (e.g. IBM's).

But since we're into FUD-mongering, a more likely scenario (compared to "the end of the world" for Java on Windows) is:

1. Oracle does a deal with Apple to take over Apple's rights to the Java-on-Mac codebase.
2. Oracle "monetizes their investment" by selling Java-on-Mac licenses to developers or end-user.

That would certainly be "in character" for Oracle, and they'd be within their rights to do this.  It wouldn't make them popular with the open-source community, but the signs are that they don't really care about that.

Comment: I think the most likely scenario is that Oracle just takes a long time to come out with a Mac port and it's low quality (your users now have to use X11 instead of having a native app).

Comment: @Gabe - you could be right.  It depends on whether Apple would be willing to deal with Oracle, or whether this is Steve Jobs trying to close the gates to his walled garden.

Comment: The gates have been slowly closing for some time now (Carbon, Flash, Java). I think it's safe to say that if Apple was willing to let somebody produce a high-quality Java implementation, they would have done it years ago when they were short on cash. I'm afraid that "Write once, run anywhere" no longer fits Apple's strategy.

Comment: And now we have Oracle Java 7 for OS X.

Comment: So the first part of my scenario has happened ... but not the second part (yet :-) )

Answer (score 1):

This strongly depends if Apple will make it an optional download (like Rosetta) or completely leave it.

If it is an optional download, you are in the same situation as under Windows.

If abandoned, then you must consider if OS X is a supported platform anymore.

You may in any case strongly consider supporting the OpenJDK project which currently is the best bet for filling the void Apple is creating here.

Comment: It turned out it was an optional download for 10.7 and 10.8 with the latest updates explicitly preparing for Oracle Java.